# What are the differences between select2, and select2 full?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Right now I am wondering what the full differences between select2, and select2 full are. I can not find a webpage that goes into details about them in the docs. The docs just mention compatability modules, and the mousewheel plugin, but there's also new config options for dropdownCssClass as well so I find this a little confusing. I was going to adopt it to use the dropdownCssClass config option, but I want to know what else I’ll get from it. I'm also curious if select2 full is being as actively maintained as select2, but can't find that information on that as well

Comment: From what I seen on the source files, it seems to be no difference at all: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2

Comment: Wow, I had a brief look and the docs are amazingly unhelpful [this](https://select2.org/getting-started/builds-and-modules) mentions that the full build has compatibility modules (among other things) -> the page for compatibility modules links back to the previous page. I can't see a complete listing of what's in the full build.

Comment: You can check here: https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/develop/Gruntfile.js to see how are these builds configured and what are the differences. .

Comment: Woah, having to look at the gruntfile to see how the builds are configured is pretty unhelpful but answers the question. Thanks @JakubMatczak

Answer (score 4):

**Standard (select2.js / select2.min.js)**

> This is the build that most people should be using for Select2. It
>   includes the most commonly used features.

**Full (select2.full.js / select2.full.min.js)**

> You should only use this build if you need the additional features
>   from Select2, like the [compatibility modules](https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35) or recommended includes
>   like [jquery.mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)

If you want to read more, you can find it on [select2 official website](https://select2.org/getting-started/builds-and-modules).